# Increase the value of DataTable Cell by 1

Tags: c#

I want to increase the value of a Cell in a `DataTable` by 1.

```
jangoTable.Rows[1]["stayCount"] += 1 ;
```

Comment: your code isn't work?gives you any error?

Comment: Are you dealing with an object type ?  On the LHS (left Hand Side) of the += operator?

Comment: jangoTable.Rows[1]["stayCount"] = (int)jangoTable.Rows[1]["stayCount"] + 1; OK